# Does css position property affect priority of z-index?

Tags: css, z-index

I have read severals questions/articles about z-index on stackoverflow, but I am still unable to solve last problem with z-index property on my webpage.

The simple question:
 Does element with `position:absolute` always overlap the element with `postion:relative`, no matter of value of their z-index?

I need to force element with `position:relative;z-index:50` to overlap the element with `postion:aboslute;z-index:5;`. I would even use script if necessary.

There is webpage with that issue: [sample page](http://www.grafika-studio.cz/hde2/index.html)

Note: That webpage is highly based on z-index, and there is a lot of not elegant css solutions (sticky footer, background repeat). I it's almost working but as you can see, the  `<div id="mainContent"> some text </div>` have position relative and have negative bottom margin to overlap the footer. But the footer (`<div id="footerFixWrapper"></div>`) have absolute postion, and its overlaps mainConetnet no matter it have lower z-index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if the divs exist in different stacking contexts.  In this situation, z-index will not affect either in relation to each other.

CSS-Discuss Wiki has the details: http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Overlapping_And_ZIndex

Comment: so... there is no solution for my webpage :(

Comment: No, you should be able to fix, but you need to place them within the same stacking order.